# Longman English Dictionary Database

Tags: data-request, language, english, dictionary

Is Longman English Dictionary as database available for public or should I digitalise it?

I plan to create an app based on Longman English Dictionary, but I need the database somehow. Any idea how?

Comment: The legal page is not so friendly - http://uk.pearson.com/legal-notice

Comment: What do you think, if I use only the result of the online dictionary, can I use meaning / example sentence of a word in my quiz app?

Comment: Doesn't look so good, but I'm no expert... 
> Users are not entitled to modify the content of this Site or reproduce, republish, distribute, transmit, link, frame or deep-link it on any other website without the express permission of Pearson. 
> Users may not distribute, transmit, reproduce or publish by electronic or any other means any part of the data without the prior written permission of Pearson.
> Users may not create a database in electronic or structured manual form by systematically downloading and storing all or any of the content. 
> All other rights reserved.

Comment: @philshem You should really post this as an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular dictionary's [legal notice](http://uk.pearson.com/legal-notice) says that:

> Users are not entitled to [...] transmit [..] it on any other website without the express permission of Pearson.
>
> You must not use data mining, robots, scraping or similar data gathering or extraction methods on **any part of** this Site without our express prior written consent *(my emphasis)*

So either contact them, or use a more open dictionary.
See this list of [open English dictionaries](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/free-english-dictionary).

Comment: Interesting that google translate has the same monolingual definitions as longman, do you think they have an agreement makes allowed to use longman's database?

Comment: @János: Yes I am sure they negotiated a special agreement.