# Free English Dictionary

Tags: data-request, english, dictionary

Looking for a free monolingual english dictionary like oxford or longman dictionary, but which I can freely use, without violating any intellectual property. I want to use it in my iOS app.

I need definition /meaning of english words expressed with simpler words. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) stackexchange site has a question with answers related to your question

> What's the largest open-source dictionary that includes brief definitions of each word?

[Source](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8237/61410)

The popular answer is [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) from Princeton. You can either browse or download the full data set, although it's about 10 years old.

The [license](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/license/) allows commercial use.

---

Here is an example of the page for Data:

```
http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=data
```

And the definitions

> S: (n) data, information (a collection of facts from which conclusions may be drawn) "statistical data"
>
> S: (n) datum, data point (an item of factual information derived from measurement or research)

Comment: In Oxford I can find definitions like *prospects: chances or opportunities for success or wealth*, wordnetweb contains no such a compact definition, only synonym, wordnetweb does seems not so professional

Answer (score 10):

[Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/) is the Wikimedia project's dictionary. Here is an example of a page, although the definitions are still quite technical:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/data#English
```

Additionally, like [simple.wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), there is a [Simple English Wiktionary](http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/Main_Page) page. Here is an example:

```
http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/data
```

The definition you are looking for:

> Data is information, such as facts, numbers, photographs, etc.

The [license](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:GNU_Free_Documentation_License) is GNU Free Documentation License ([text](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Text_of_the_GNU_Free_Documentation_License)).

---

**DOWNLOAD**

All the Wikimedia projects use the same data dump scheme ([backup index](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html)).

The Simple Wiktionary line looks like this:

```
2014-12-12 20:44:20 simplewiktionary: Dump complete
```

And the most recent link is:

```
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/simplewiktionary/20141212/
```

From this page, you are looking for the top files:

> Articles, templates, media/file descriptions, and primary meta-pages, in multiple bz2 streams, 100 pages per stream

The index file (simplewiktionary-20141212-pages-articles-multistream-index.txt.bz2, 144 KB) contains a listing of all the pages. Here are some randomly selected records:

[image]

You can use these words to then find definitions from the pages. I extracted the XML dump and put on pastebin the data for the page "Data" - [LINK](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qx7RHHft). The part you are looking for can be parsed out from these lines:

```
{{noun3|data|datum|data}}
#{{uncountable}} '''Data''' is [[information]], such as [[fact]]s, [[number]]s, [[photograph]]s, etc.
#: ''A [[study]] using [[experiment]]al '''data''' from ten schools found no [[difference]] between [[method]]s.''
```

---

**IMPORT**

Here are some instructions on how to import the XML data dump - [LINK](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps).

Some possible tools, depending on your skills:

- [xml2sql](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/xml2sql) (multiplatform C tool)
- [Pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) (Python, requires registering your app, but doesn't require reconstructing database)
- [mwdumper](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Mwdumper) (Java)